# How to set value without expiry using EasyCache

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, caching, redis, in-memory

I am integrating the easy caching in the application. I see they have set method to add cache into expiry but this method as for expiry time compulsory.
Is there a way I can add/set cache without expiry?

Comment: Have you considered setting the duration to a very long period of time (e.g. 3 years)?

Comment: @mjwills: don't want to set is explicitly. Just wanted to go with server life time.

Comment: I understand what you want - but the workaround I suggested is simple and will work. No server ever runs for 3 years, uninterrupted...

Comment: Could you please tell me which provider you have used inmemory or redis?

Comment: @BrandoZhang: I am using both, InMemory and Redis.

Answer (score 0):

According to the source codes, I found there is a `ExpirationScanFrequency` attribute which will check the cache's expire time and if the cache has exceed the expire time, it will remove it.

[Source codes](https://github.com/dotnetcore/EasyCaching/blob/934c31cc4cd64468cd2e6e51b1bf3d4417b749f9/src/EasyCaching.InMemory/Internal/InMemoryCaching.cs) as below:

```
    private void StartScanForExpiredItems()
    {
        var utcNow = SystemClock.UtcNow;
        if (TimeSpan.FromSeconds(_options.ExpirationScanFrequency) < utcNow - _lastExpirationScan)
        {
            _lastExpirationScan = utcNow;
            Task.Factory.StartNew(state => ScanForExpiredItems((InMemoryCaching)state), this,
                CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.DenyChildAttach, TaskScheduler.Default);
        }
    }

    private void ScanForExpiredItems(InMemoryCaching cache)
    {
        var now = SystemClock.UtcNow;
        foreach (var entry in cache._memory.Values.Where(x => x.ExpiresAt < now))
        {
            cache.Remove(entry.Key);
        }
    }
```

If you want these cache never expired, you could set this value to 0 and then it will never check the expire time.

More details, you could refer to below codes:

Notice: This setting only work for the in memory cache and there is no setting in redis.

```
    //configuration
    services.AddEasyCaching(options => 
    {

         options.UseInMemory(config => 
        {
          config.DBConfig = new InMemoryCachingOptions
            {
                // scan time, default value is 60s
                ExpirationScanFrequency = 0, 
                // total count of cache items, default value is 10000
                SizeLimit = 100 
             };
     
         }, "m2");

    });
```